# jQuery mobile and basket handling: is there a good howto outthere?

Tags: jquery-mobile

If you google for "jQuery mobile basket" you'll find only tons of books about "jQuery mobile" and the button: "Add to basket"...

Here's how I did it, and it just showed me it's not the good way (= bad user interaction):

MP = Mobile Phone

1. MP: create local basket (JavaScript class)
2. MP: download the whole page with all products, but hidden (= different pages).
3. MP: when selecting products, only change page
4. MP: each time **adding** a product, make and AJAX call so that *everything is kept on the server side*
5. MP: each time **removing** a product, make and AJAX call so that *everything is kept on the server side*
6. Server Side: keep all in a session, until either it expires, or the user on the MP register. If so, add new record in database with all information.

The big problem is when adding or removing. Sometimes, just making an Ajax call is damn slow and this is not acceptable: you often add many products, so you may have to wait for each call. Not user friendly at all.

My (future) Website works perfectly this way, I didn't know the Mobile version would be so problematic.

What could be the "Mobile version" solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible implementation could have a `basket` structure as a global variable in the Javascript and synchronize that with server side structure.

The JS code on pages on MP should only add/remove from local `basket` structure.

Then there could be a timer to sync the local `basket` to server `basket` using Ajax calls at regular time intervals.

This way you do not make (slower!!!) Ajax calls on each add/delete but batch up deltas to your server.

Answer (score 0):

You could store whatever is in the basket in a global variable. Because variables aren't deleted between pages when using normal jQuery-mobile transitions (only the `data-role="page"` is loaded), you can use this variable to store the items. I think a JSON object would be easiest to use to store all properties of "basketed" items.

You would have to make sure though that your variables aren't delete by a some `rel="external"` transition somewhere. Maybe a backup on your site would provide some protection against these cases.

Comment: And if the user refreshes the page? Or closes the browser then comes back a few minutes later? The solution I've done works for both cases.

Comment: That is why you could backup the basket to your site. When opening a page you could start an AJAX request to check if the basket contents are correct. This way you still retain the speed because it is an asynchronous request and usually the basket is filled by the global variable. But when the basket contents are lost you can restore then from the server.

Comment: I'll think about that. Maybe if the basket is modified, I launch a timer, then if it's not modified (= no add/remove) after a certain amount of time I send it to the server.

Comment: Perhaps you could also employ cookies, because they persist through refreshes.

Comment: I think I'll use HTML5 sessionStorage Object => http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp.